# Ramsey numbers - Graph Theory - Invitation to discrete mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

My school chose the worst math textbook for undergrad graph theory course. This textbook i think should be used for grad level. I have done the a and b and I am working on C. Please give me some tips or if you can give me a trivial explanation i would appreciate very much as I am not that fast at learning. Thanks you.

---

[image]

Textbook : Invitation to discrete mathematics.

Comment: What are the functions $\alpha(G)$ and $\omega(G)$, that combine to give $f(G)$?

Comment: @Joffan: The independence number and the clique number: the maximum size of an independent set of vertices and of a clique, respectively.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks, I hadn't seen $\omega()$ before so I thought I'd check on both.

Comment: maximum number of vertices of a complete subgraph and the maximum number of vertices of an independent set in a graph.

Comment: Why don't you tell us at which point you got stock, so we don't waste time telling you stuff you already know? I guess you succeeded in proving that $f(1)\ge1?$ Then did you figure out why $f(2)\ge2?$ Did you work all parts of (a) and (b) and you just need help with (c)?

Comment: i have done with part a and b. I just don't know where to start with c.

Comment: Hint: $\omega(C_n) = 2$ for all $n\geqslant 4$.

Comment: Just to reply to the comment on the book. Personally think it is a good book for undergrads.
From the Preface: "The readership can include early undergraduate students of mathematics of computer science with a standard mathematical preparation from high school...".  "One-star exercises usually need some clever idea or some slightly more advanced mathematical knowledge... classifiction of difficulty is subjective... if you cant solve some no-star exercise don't get desperate"

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Show that $\alpha(C_{n,k})=\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k+1}\right\rfloor$. What is $\omega(C_{n,k})$? What happens if $k+1$ is not a divisor of $n$?